# Optimizing a recursive UDF with a temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, user-defined-functions

I have the folowing function that loops through a tree structure to see if any of the child notes contain a property:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_FamilyHasCar] ( @PersonId Integer ) RETURNS bit
as
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Out bit = 0
    Declare @Count int
    Select @Count = count(*) from car WHERE owner_id = @PersonId and type = 2
    if @Count = 0
        begin 
            declare @tbl_temp table (personId int)
            Declare @Id int
            insert into @tbl_temp(personId) (select id from person where parent_id = @PersonId) 
            While (Select Count(*) From @tbl_temp) > 0
                Begin
                    Select Top 1 @Id = personId From @tbl_temp
                    set @Out = dbo.ufn_FamilyHasCar(@Id)
                    if @Out = 1
                        break
                    Delete from @tbl_temp Where personId = @Id
                End
        end
    else 
    set @Out = 1
RETURN @Out
END
GO
```

This seems to be the bottleneck in my current implementation, so I'm asking if and how I can improve the performance of the udf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would replace this with a recursive CTE:

```
with pp as (
      select p.id
      from person p
      where p.id = @personid
      union all
      select p.id
      from pp join
           person p
           on pp.parentid = p.id
    )
select (case when count(*) > 0 then 1 else 0 end)
from pp join
     car c
     on pp.id = c.owner_id and type = 2;
```

`COUNT(*)` is the clearest way to express the query.  However, if there are lots of matches (say more than a few dozen), then the extra overhead for the aggregation is overkill, and you can use exists instead:

```
with pp as ( . . .)
select (case when exists (select 1 from pp join car cc on pp.id = c.owner_id and type = 2)
             then 1 else 0
        end);
```

Comment: Does then replace the calls to the UDF or should it be inside the UDF?

Comment: @Bugman . . . Either way.  You don't need the recursion, so you can replace the UDF depending on what your code looks like.